# Limiting number of user clicks to reduce micro: best method of implementation?

Tags: algorithm, multiplayer

I'm making a client-server game where the user can select armies and move them from one place to another.

In a bid to reduce the advantage of "being able to click faster" I've decided to implement several anti-micro measures, one of which is to limit the number of clicks (or move orders) that the user may issue.

In order to discourage individual unit micro, group move orders and individual unit orders both count as one move order.

What's the best way to implement this? I've thought of 2 ways:

1. Have countdown-timers both on the client and server. The timers must be synchronized - perhaps by the server sending the countdown time to the client. If the client issues a move order before the countdown is finished, the order is ignored.
2. Have randomly generated "move tokens" issued from the server to the client every few seconds. In order for an order to be accepted it must come with a valid move token, and each "move token" is only valid for one mode order.

Which way of implementing it is better? Any other good ways?

Comment: Are you trying to keep this from being turn based or trying to make it more turn based? Each would have different approaches

Comment: Don't prevent bad actions, prevent rewards for bad actions. Otherwise you generate frustration.

Comment: "*In a bid to reduce the advantage of "being able to click faster"*" Don't do that. Stop trying to control how your players play the game.

Answer (score 11):

Simply limiting the number of clicks a user can make approaches the problem from the wrong angle. At best, your players will perceive your game's input controls as unresponsive and glitchy. At worst, they will notice that you are using a cheap trick to prevent them from getting better.

If you want your game to be decided by macro-management strategy and not by micro-management skills, then you should approach this from a game-design perspective. Design your game in a way that being capable of making more actions-per-minute than your opponent just won't help you to win the game.

- Make units act smart and autonomous so they don't need the player's help to reach their full potential.

  - Have them automatically prefer targets which are vulnerable to their weapons
  - Have them automatically prefer targets which are already damaged, but have them still avoid unnecessary overkill
  - Make them capable of pulling off advanced maneuvers on their own (like kiting an opponent with less range and speed)
  - Have them use their special abilities on their own and not just when the player tells them to
  - Give your units some common sense self-preservation instincts (automatically move to nearby cover if under fire, automatically flee if attacked by an enemy and they can't attack back, etc.)
  - Add a lot of settings to dictate unit behavior for each unit. Any of the above behaviors should be possible to switch off and on, in case the player puts the units in a situation where these features are counter-productive.
- Don't make combat too fast-paced, so players have more time to react if they notice they are losing a battle. You can do that by increasing the number of hits each unit takes.
- Find and eliminate any exploits which require fast micro-management (like getting around attack cooldowns by quickly loading and unloading units into transports). Many RTS games intentionally leave such exploits in the game to extend the skill ceiling. If you want to keep the skill ceiling low, you should get rid of them. You might want to watch some videos showing off micro-management tricks in other RTS games and make sure none of these will work in your game.

  - Or alternatively, program your unit AI so that units can do these tricks  on their own, as already mentioned before.
- Dive deep into the science of multi-agent route-finding algorithms to make sure that getting a large army from A to B as fast as possible doesn't require more than one click. There is a lot of research to this.

You might even go so far and remove direct unit control altogether. Let the player give indirect strategic priorities instead and have the player's units act on those priorities on their own.

Answer (score 3):

You could design a "penalty" in to the units when they receive commands. So an idle unit could respond to a command immediately, while one that already has a command will take some time to respond.

Conceptually, following a command takes a unit away from their idle state, and in order to receive another command they need to go back to that idle state first.

This avoids the issue that Phillip raises:

> Simply limiting the number of clicks a user can make approaches the problem from the wrong angle. At best, your players will perceive your game's input controls as unresponsive and glitchy. At worst, they will notice that you are using a cheap trick to prevent them from getting better.

So long as you make the delay seem natural.

Some examples:

- A tank in motion can't just spontaneously turn around
- Perhaps some time to change a target, or switch weapons

Comment: Though I do agree it may be better to design around the macro aspects, I wanted to provide an answer to the specific problem.